# Is there a natural Hilbert structure on jet spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory

In a nutshell, I am trying to apply harmonic analysis on Lie groups
to symmetry groups of differential equations. As far as I understand,
to this aim I need to present the structure of Hilbert spaces on jet
bundles. So my question: is there some literature on this topic and 
whether this problem well-posed?

Answer (score 2):

The fiber of an infinite jet bundle is modeled on the projective limit $\mathbb{R}^\infty = \varprojlim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{R}^n$. It does not have a Hilbert topology. Rather it has a Fréchet topology. A standard reference for this is

> *Michor, P.W.*, Manifolds of differentiable mappings, Shiva Mathematics Series, 3. Orpington, Kent (U.K.): Shiva Publishing Limited. IV, 158 p. [ZBL0433.58001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0433.58001).